# Did the real Stillwater ever have a problem with Almost Famous using their name?

Tags: copyright, almost-famous

In the movie [*Almost Famous* (2000)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181875/), the band Stillwater was supposedly an amalgamation of Poco, The Eagles, Led Zeppelin and a few other bands that Cameron Crowe had actually written articles about early in his career with Rolling Stone.  However, there was a real band named [Stillwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stillwater_(band)) that was actually active during the years the movie supposedly took place.

I searched pretty extensively on Google but can't come up with any info; did the real Stillwater ever have any objection to their name being used in the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a 2003 interview with Bobby Golden, one of the founders of the band, that can be found [here](http://www.sweethomemusic.fr/Interviews/StillwaterUS.php)

> **Luc Brunot:** **One last question. You certainly know that Cameron Crowe, in his movie "Almost Famous" gave the name of Stillwater to the rock band which is the center of the film. Did he contact you and sign an agreement and are there facts referring to the real Stillwater's life style? The director is a fan of Southern rock and did he made many allusions to the Allman Brothers and Lynyrd Skynyrd, all through all the movie.**
>
> **Bobby Golden:** I lived and worked in Italy when I received a part of the rights paid by Dreamworks to Stillwater to have used the name of Stillwater in the film "Almost Famous". After having called at house to know why I touched these rights, I discovered that the company of Steven Spielberg, Dreamworks, had contacted Sebie Lacey, our singer to establish a deal concerning the use of the name. The young Cameron had seen us in the seventies, in Macon, Georgia, at the time of a concert organized by Capricorn Records, whereas he wrote in Rolling Stones. Even if the film is not devoted to us, it remember me some good memories of our ten years of tours and recordings when we were. almost famous.

Comment: That's interesting that he specifically sought out a relatively unknown band for use in the movie, I thought for sure it would be a case where their name was used and Crowe didn't realize a band with that name actually existed.  Now I like this movie even more for that "shout out" to a band he liked that never got famous!